# Firestore check if cache data exists in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

To reduce my document reads, I want to read firestore data from the cache:

```
result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(
              'path/toDocument')
          .get(cacheAvailable ? GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
```

This works. But if there doesn't exist cache data, how can I get an bool e.g `cacheAvailable`, to check if there exists the cache data or not?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fetch your data from your cache at first and if it fails get the data from the server.

As `get()` [throws a `FirebaseException` if it tries to read from an unexisting cache](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Source-class.html) using a `try catch` could work.

**Code Sample**

```dart
final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('path/toDocument');
QuerySnapshot results;

try {
  // By default we try to read the data from the cache.
  results = await collection.get(GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
} on FirebaseException catch (e) {
  // Getting data from cache failed so we get the result from the server.
  results = await collection.get();
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. FirebaseException doesn't throw an error.

Comment: If you didn't have any exception, did you get an empty QuerySnapshotPlatform ? If yes you could add a condition to perform the collection.get() when getting an empty object with no documents.